# Getting error can not get header after they send when read files from directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to get the name and created date of the files. In the code below it throws error when I call the api. It is reading the directory and printing all the file names but it's not sending back to callback. Any idea what is implemented wrong?

service.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var async = require('async');
var currentDate = new Date();
var objToReturn = [];
var logsDirectory = './logs'

function readDirectory(env, callback) {
    fs.readdir(logsDirectory + '/' + env, function(err, files) {
            // loop through each file
            async.eachSeries(files, function(file, done) {
                var dirPath = logsDirectory + '/' + env;
                var filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);
                var fileInfo = {};
                fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.info("File doesn't exist");
                    } else {
                        fileInfo.fileDate = stats.birthtime;
                        fileInfo.filename = file;
                        objToReturn.push(fileInfo);
                        done();
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.info('error', err);
                return;
            }
            // when you're done reading all the files, do something...
            console.log('before Callback', objToReturn);
            callback(objToReturn);
        });
}


exports.readDirectory = readDirectory;
```

app.js

```
var stDirectory = require('./app/serverfiles/stDir');
app.get('/getAllFiles',function(req,res){
var env = req.query.env
console.log('printing',env);
    stDirectory.readDirectory(env,function(files){
        res.json(files);
        console.log('Api files',files);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- instead of passing the "final" handler to `async.eachSeries()`, you're passing it to `fs.readdir()`, so `callback` will never get called;
- you're declaring `objToReturn` *outside* of the function, which isn't a good idea because multiple requests could be handled in parallel;
- you're not handling any errors properly;
- you should really use the Node.js callback idiom of calling callbacks with two arguments, the first being errors (if there are any) and the second being the result of the asynchronous operation.

The code below should fix these issues:

```
function readDirectory(env, callback) {
  let objToReturn = [];
  fs.readdir(
    logsDirectory + "/" + env,
    function(err, files) {
      if (err) return callback(err);

      // loop through each file
      async.eachSeries(files, function(file, done) {
        var dirPath = logsDirectory + "/" + env;
        var filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);
        var fileInfo = {};
        fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
          if (err) {
            console.info("File doesn't exist");
            return done(err);
          } else {
            fileInfo.fileDate = stats.birthtime;
            fileInfo.filename = file;
            objToReturn.push(fileInfo);
            done();
          }
        });
      }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.info("error", err);
          return callback(err);
        }
        // when you're done reading all the files, do something...
        console.log("before Callback", objToReturn);
        callback(null, objToReturn);
      }
    );
}

// To call it:
stDirectory.readDirectory(env, function(err, files) {
  if (err) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  } else {
    res.json(files);
    console.log('Api files',files);
  }
});
```

You should also consider using `async.mapSeries()` instead of `async.eachSeries()` and using a separate array (`objToReturn`).

Comment: it worked...Thank you for explanation that make sense i will make changes